# What exactly is javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I am currently taking an AP Java class and I can't even begin to understand what "javadoc" is whatsoever, all that I seem to take out so far is that its a "different" way of commenting when creating an API so a programmer can better read the code . . .

I am new to this and I would appreciate any beginning point so I can at least grab on to the concept.

Comment: JavaDoc is awesome.  Yes, it's a way to comment you code, but you can use the JavaDoc tool to generate API documentation like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), which provides a (reasonably) standard document across multiple APIs.  Many IDE's also use it to present tooltips and extended help while you are coding...

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"JavaDoc is awesome."*  That's a +1.  I get sick of waiting for Netbeans to look up JDocs from the net (? must figure out how to configure it to get them from the local machine) & just have that link in your comment (to the main docs) constantly open in 'tab 2' of FF ('tab 1' is GMail).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think if you can download the JavaDocs as a zip file, you can go to Tools -> Java Platforms, select the version of Java, go to the `JavaDoc` tab and add a reference to the zip file...I may be off doing something for a little while ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  (After having tested that approach) I think you're right!  The attempt to 'attach a directory' showed some funky results, I specified the top level where `index.html` is, & it translated that to ..sample apps. for JMF(?!?).  In any case, I then linked directly to the Zip and now docs. in NB are quick and smooth to pop-up.  It sure helps for places like here, where my connection to the net is a pair of twisted copper wires (OK - it is actually a wireless connection - but about as slow).

Answer (score 6):

I was thinking about how to describe it, but honestly I think the SO `Javadoc` tag does a very good job:

> Javadoc is an extensible documentation generation system which reads
>   specially formatted comments in Java source code and generates
>   compiled documentation. It is typically used to produce API
>   documentation in the form of HTML web pages.

Many IDEs also make use of Javadocs to generate contextual API descriptions.  Javadocs can make the difference between an extremely obscure library and something that is a delight to use.

Javadocs, **use them!!**

Comment: "generates compiled documentation" that is what I don't understand . . . where exactly does it generate them? . . . does it simply make a simple html document or is somehow displayed in your IDE?

Comment: @someone The output is simply HTML, nothing particularly special.  But most IDE's have the ability to parse these and display them within the IDE (ie, so when you're looking up methods, it can display the JavaDoc for that method), some also parse the JavaDoc out of the source code as well...

Comment: @someone; have a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#runningjavadoc

Comment: @YasinOkumus If you use Eclipse, you can let it generate JavaDoc for u

Comment: @LittleChild; Well, I guess there is a misunderstanding about "generate". In Eclipse, when you write ie. /** then you get the continuation of the JavaDoc markdown and that is what you call "generation" ? Then yes, you are right. But by using JavaDoc style markdown, can you generate HTML of the Javadoc in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: @YasinOkumus there is an option called `Generate JavaDoc` and it makes the HTML pages for you. Here: http://www.eclipse-blog.org/eclipse-ide/generating-javadoc-in-eclipse-ide.html

Comment: @YasinOkumus I am glad I could help you out :)

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you need to look up a Java method, you Google the name of the method and refer to the docs to see what it does. Great !

But how did these docs come in place ? How was so much documentation generated ? Was someone hired to do that ?

Well, whenever you write code you need to properly explain it in the source files using comments. `/** */` marks a comment block. Now, `javadoc` is responsible for parsing these comments into documentation (It makes HTML files out of these comments). So, nobody was hired just `javadoc` was executed.

Here is an example of beginning comment:

```
/**
* Classname
* Version info
* Copyright notice
*/
```

But that is not all. `javadoc` is very powerful. It allows you to even write basic HTML inside the comments and then it parses the HTML to come up with a proper output. `/** <html> */` That is why some JacaDoc pages have tables. These were made using the `<td>` and `<tr>` tags in HTML

For example,

```
/**
   * First paragraph.
   * <p><ul>
   * <li>the first item
   * <li>the second item
   * <li>the third item
   * <ul><p>
   * Second paragraph.
   */
```

If you want javadoc to work properly with your code, follow the Java Code Convention : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf if your code adheres to the convention, it becomes easy for javadoc to make the documentation.

Here is the official Oracle guide to writing documentation comments: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Comment: This is a good start, I think JavaDoc is a "term" used to describe 1- A tool for the generation of documentation; 2- The conventions expected to be followed by that tool; 3- The output generated by that tool...or something along those lines...that should make it a better answer ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Have a look at the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc is a program that reads your java files and creates HTML documentation out of them. You use it by adding comments with documentation, then invoking it.

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc is a program much like a compiler that reads your codes and plucks out certain parts of it in order to create a (very very very very very) useful documentation in the form of html pages. The [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) pages you use for standard java code is made using Javadoc.

While parsing your code, Javadocs looks for two things: code structure and Javadoc comments. The code structure is just the code itself. That is used to build up the basic structure of a page (ie class name, fields, methods, etc). Javadoc comments are special comments that start with `/**` instead of the usual `/*` As far as the regular java compiler is concerned, it makes no difference though. Once in a Javadoc comment you write about the specific aspect of the code you are referencing and are able to use html tags as well as some other special syntax. You can learn more about it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sun defines JavaDoc as follows (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html):

```
Javadoc is a tool for generating API documentation in HTML format
from doc comments in source code
```

The comments have a certain format that has become widely known as "Javadoc". You can see more details at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html